# How to send the id of iterator from <a href=""> to javascript function

Tags: javascript, struts2

I want to sand the id of the iterator through link
I try but not working

My Link is like that

```
 <s:iterator  value="answerList" status="id">

 <a  class="link" href="javascript:countactu_Form('+"%{#id.index}"+')" >add Comment</a>
 <div id="Contactu-Form-%{#id.index}" >
   <s:textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="60" theme="simple" />
  </div>
```

And my function is like that

```
 function countactu_Form(id){
            alert("123456789");
            alert(id);
            $('#Contactu-Form-'+id).animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            },150, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }
```

Comment: try this and it should work `<a  class="link" href="javascript:countactu_Form('<s:property value="%{#id.index}"/>')" >add Comment</a>`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Pls post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please next time post the "view-source" of the link

Applying the suggestion by @Umesh and changing the script to work in more browsers, try

`<a  class="link" href="#" onclick="return countactu_Form('<s:property value="%{#id.index}"/>')">add Comment</a>`

and change the function to return false

```
function countactu_Form(id){
  $('#Contactu-Form-'+id).animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  },150, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan-it still not get the id. It just pass the string %{#id.index} as id

Comment: @mplungjan: you already edited your answer and that's i believe enough for someone facing same issue :)

Comment: Ok, It was just your rep for the actual solution